# Java NoClassDefFoundError : Apache Flink Complex Event Processing

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I am trying to understand the Apache Flink CEP program to monitor rack temperatures in a data center as described by [Flink Official Documentation](https://github.com/tillrohrmann/cep-monitoring). But when I follow the steps and create a jar using `mvn clean package` and tried to execute the package using the command

```
java -cp "../cep-monitoring-1.0.jar" org.stsffap.cep.monitoring.CEPMonitoring
```

But I get the following error,

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I tried different variations of giving the classpath as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath) but getting the same error. Can someone point out my mistake in running the program?

Comment: Are you trying to submit a job to the local flink cluster?

Comment: Yes. So the flink cluster should be executed explicitly in the background?

Comment: You could include a piece of your pom.xml to better understand if you have the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cep example](https://github.com/tillrohrmann/cep-monitoring) uses flink version 1.3.2. So here are the steps to run it.

1. Install version 1.3.2 of apache flink. (`wget` it from [here](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#all-releases) and extract it).
2. cd into `flink-1.3.2`
3. `./bin/start-local.sh`, this will start the flink cluster. Do `cd ..`.
4. Clone [this repo](https://github.com/tillrohrmann/cep-monitoring) using `git clone` and `cd` into that.
5. `mvn clean package` to build the project. This will create `target` directory.
6. Run `../flink-1.3.2/bin/flink run target/cep-monitoring-1.0.jar`, to start the process.
7. In separate terminal the output can be logged like this (assuming that you are in same directory as previous step) `tail -f ../flink-1.3.2/log/flink-*-jobmanager-*.out` (* will be replaced by specific user detail, press tab to autocomplete those).

Here is the sample output,

```
rshah9@bn18-20:~/tools/cep-monitoring-master$ tail -f ../flink-1.3.2/log/flink-rshah9-jobmanager-0-bn18-20.dcs.mcnc.org.out
TemperatureWarning(9, 102.45860162626161)
TemperatureWarning(6, 113.21295716135027)
TemperatureWarning(5, 105.46064102697723)
TemperatureWarning(0, 106.44635415722034)
TemperatureWarning(4, 112.07396748089734)
TemperatureWarning(9, 114.53346561628322)
TemperatureWarning(3, 109.05305417712648)
TemperatureWarning(7, 112.3698094257147)
TemperatureWarning(3, 107.78609416982076)
TemperatureWarning(9, 107.34373990230458)
TemperatureWarning(5, 111.46480675461656)
```

Answer (score 2):

To submit a job to the local Flink cluster:

1. Run Flink.

`/path/to/flink-1.4.0/bin/start-local.sh`

2. Submit the job.

`/path/to/flink-1.4.0/bin/flink run -c com.package.YourClass /path/to/jar.jar`

Alternatively you can run the job simply from your IDE:

Your job in this case will be run in a Flink environement.
Check Flink's example: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/wordcount/WordCount.java